# How to open telnet/ssh to Dlink DSL-225 router?

Tags: linux, router, ssh, telnet, nmap

have D-link DSL 225 router that locate at 192.168.1.1 , with nmap I get

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
21/tcp  open  ftp
22/tcp  open  ssh
23/tcp  open  telnet
80/tcp  open  http
631/tcp open  ipp
```

when I tried `ssh 192.168.1.1 I` get `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

When I tried `telnet 192.168.1.1` , I get

```
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

When I tried `ftp 192.168.1.1` , I get

```
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
```

In verbose mode

```
ssh 192.168.1.1 -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jobs/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jobs/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jobs/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jobs/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jobs/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jobs/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jobs/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jobs/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

How can I open telnet / ssh to this router?

Comment: Is 192.168.1.1 actually the D-Link?

Comment: @Havegooda  yes sure , When I enter to this ip I get the router web

Comment: Is this a wireless router? How are you connecting, hardwire or through wireless? It's possible that the router is refusing SSH/22 connections if it's not through ethernet due to a security policy, perhaps? Can you paste the verbose output? (-v flag)

Comment: @Havegooda I attached ssh verbose , I connecting wireless to the router

Comment: It appears your config is only set to use a PKI cert to connect? I'd take a look at that and see if there's a way to enable user/pass authentication. That router is relatively old, so I doubt it supports PKI in the first place.